# C# Split up words with two colons

Tags: c#, string, split

I have a incoming string looking like this: xxxx::xxxxx::xxxxxx

How can I split the string after every '::'? I can get it to do with just one colon, but not two.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
var splitted = 
         yourString.Split(new []{"::"},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

You can split only on `string[]` not on `string`

EDIT:

as Adil said you can always use `Regex.Split`

```
var splitted = Regex.Split(yourString, "::");
```

Comment: Could be splitted without string array using Regex.Split var arr = Regex.Split(string, "::");

Answer (score 0):

Or you could use this code snippet :

```
        List<string> resList = new List<string>();
        int fIndx = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
        {
            if(a[i] == ':' && a[i+1] == ':') 
            {
                resList.Add(a.Substring(fIndx, i - fIndx));
                fIndx = i + 2;
            }
        }
```